# Pass JSON to Dynamics CRM SharedVariable instead of string

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamics-crm, shared-variable

I have data which is serialized as JSON which then has to be added to the Dynamics PluginExeutionContext in a SharedVariable. The Problem is that the JSON content is passed as string and cannot be parsed as JSON on the other side of the receiver.

This is how it is passed now:

```
   "SharedVariables": [
         "key": "Telemetry_Log",
         "value": "JsonContent"
       },
   ]
```

What I need is to have the "JsonContent" without double quotes like this

```
   "SharedVariables": [
         "key": "Telemetry_Log",
         "value": JsonContent
       },
   ]
```

First I have serialized the data into JSON and passed the string to the context like so:

```
_executionContext.SharedVariables.Add(TelemetryLogSharedVariables.CustomUserLog.GetDescription(), _loggerContainerUser.ConvertToJson()
```

second try was to return a list of CRM Entities hoping that Dynamics will serialize it.

the last try was to cast the JSON string to an object:

```
_executionContext.SharedVariables.Add(TelemetryLogSharedVariables.CustomUserLog.GetDescription(), (Object)_loggerContainerUser.ConvertToJson()
```

Nothing worked and I always got the JSON string in double quotes.

Does anybody have an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to “Create a DataContract class that will define datamodel for JSON data” and deserialize (reverse engineer) the JSON string into Object using `DataContractJsonSerializer` on the other end. [Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/10/working-with-json-objects-in-dynamics-crm-plugins/)

**Origin**: Serialize Data in JSON string

```
using (MemoryStream SerializememoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //create a sample data of type Student Class add details
                    Student NewStudent = new Student();
                    NewStudent.FullName = "Sam";
                    NewStudent.JobTitle = "Developer";
                    NewStudent.Contact = "808-2125454";
                    NewStudent.Country = "India";
                    NewStudent.ZIPCode = "400005";

                    //initialize DataContractJsonSerializer object and pass Student class type to it
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student));
                    //write newly created object(NewStudent) into memory stream
                    serializer.WriteObject(SerializememoryStream, NewStudent);

                    //use stream reader to read serialized data from memory stream
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SerializememoryStream);

                    //get JSON data serialized in string format in string variable 
                    string Serializedresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

**Destination**: Deserialize Data obtained in JSON string to an object

```
using (MemoryStream DeSerializememoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //Json String that we get from web api 
                    string ResponseString = "{\"FullName\":\"" + "Sam" + "\",\"JobTitle\":\"" + "Developer" + "\",\"Contact\":\"" + "808-124567" + "\",\"Country\":\"" + "India" + "\",\"ZIPCode\":\"" + "400005" + "\"}";

                    //initialize DataContractJsonSerializer object and pass Student class type to it
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student));

                    //user stream writer to write JSON string data to memory stream
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(DeSerializememoryStream);
                    writer.Write(ResponseString);
                    writer.Flush();

                    DeSerializememoryStream.Position = 0;
                    //get the Desrialized data in object of type Student
                    Student SerializedObject = (Student)serializer.ReadObject(DeSerializememoryStream);
                }
```

Comment: thx for your reply. so then it is not possible to have plain json as value instead of a string representation like for integers or booleans for example?

{
      "key": "IsAutoTransact",
      "value": true
},
{
      "key": "Count",
      "value": 1000
}

without double quotes?

Comment: @PaulRichardson I think only primitive datatype can be like that and JSON is not primitive

Comment: you're right. Will check with the destination. btw the destination in my case is Azure ApplicationInsights. The context is stored in a Azure queue and processed by an Azure Function which puts the data in Application Insights.

Comment: @PaulRichardson actually shared variable is for sharing data between stages of plugin like pre update and post update..